# My question is: I have an API in Django, I want to receive my JSON from the API, containing an ID that encompasses each JSON

Tags: python, json, django, api

I am not able to create an API whose ID of each object added to it is encompassing it, the ID is being created INSIDE the JSON, and I don't want that.

For example, this is the code that i have right now:

`[ { "id": 1, "event_image": "/event_images/TheTown.png", "event_name": "The Town", "event_price": "500.00", "event_date": "2, 3, 7, 9 e 10 de Set", "event_time_start": "14:00:00", "event_time_ends": "02:00:00", "event_location": "Av. Sen. Teotônio Vilela, 261 - Interlagos, São Paulo - SP, 04801-010", "event_description": "The Town é um festival de música idealizado pelo empresário brasileiro Roberto Medina – mesmo criador do Rock in Rio – pela primeira vez em 2023. É reconhecido como um dos maiores festivais musicais do Brasil. O festival é localizado no Autódromo de Interlagos em São Paulo, mesmo local onde é realizado o Lollapalooza." }, { "id": 17, "event_image": "/event_images/CasaDeShow_HD2PgOZ.jpg", "event_name": "The Town", "event_price": "200.00", "event_date": "2, 3, 7, 9 e 10 de Set", "event_time_start": "14:00:00", "event_time_ends": "02:00:00", "event_location": "Av. Sen. Teotônio Vilela, 261 - Interlagos, São Paulo - SP, 04801-010", "event_description": "The Town é um festival de música idealizado pelo empresário brasileiro Roberto Medina – mesmo criador do Rock in Rio – pela primeira vez em 2023. É reconhecido como um dos maiores festivais musicais do Brasil. O festival é localizado no Autódromo de Interlagos em São Paulo, mesmo local onde é realizado o Lollapalooza." }, ]`

Notice that the ID is INSIDE the JSON, I want it to be outside, that it encompasses the JSON, so that I can make requests to a specific ID in my front-end.

Example of that i want:

`[ "id": 1, { "event_image": "/event_images/TheTown.png", "event_name": "The Town", "event_price": "500.00", "event_date": "2, 3, 7, 9 e 10 de Set", "event_time_start": "14:00:00", "event_time_ends": "02:00:00", "event_location": "Av. Sen. Teotônio Vilela, 261 - Interlagos, São Paulo - SP, 04801-010", "event_description": "The Town é um festival de música idealizado pelo empresário brasileiro Roberto Medina – mesmo criador do Rock in Rio – pela primeira vez em 2023. É reconhecido como um dos maiores festivais musicais do Brasil. O festival é localizado no Autódromo de Interlagos em São Paulo, mesmo local onde é realizado o Lollapalooza." }, ]`

Comment: modify your query set and instead of list of record, do dict of records, something like `{ i.id: i for i in queryset}` and return this record